# With mapStateToProps, how to find and set a specific record?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Given a store with example data **store.profiles**:

```
[{"user_id":1,"stuff":"more stuff"},{"user_id":2,"stuff":"more stuff"},{"user_id":3,"stuff":"more stuff"}]
```

How can I find the current_user's specific record and send it with mapStateToProps?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  item: XXXXXXXX
});
```

Where XXXXXXXX is the current_user's id (user_id = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` method for Arrays. If `state` has a `profile` key that is an array just do this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.profiles.find(el => el.user_id === 1)
});
```

then in the component you'll have access to the `item` prop:

```
this.props.item === {"user_id":1,"stuff":"more stuff"}
```

Comment: this is great. thank you... will this error if profiles is undefined? Or will the initialValue set in the reducer handle that?

Comment: Good question. If `profiles` is `undefined` or `user_id` does not match, `find` will return `undefined`. So you'll have to customize the code to handle these cases.

Comment: Thanks but how do you handle undefined in the mapStateToProps?

Comment: Two ways. One is to write the function in a longer form (instead of immediately returning an object), check the result of `find` to see if it's undefined, and return a default value from `mapState` instead.  Another is to go ahead and let `item` be undefined, and have the component handle it by using default props, default values when destructuring, conditional logic, etc.